# how to queue render with different render settings?

Tags: rendering

I am trying to render a simple model. My laptop speed is less (for cycles). Can anyone tell me if there is an option where I can simply change settings like lighting or sampling etc. and start creating queue of renders? I don't want to render from multiple cameras. It is single camera and multiple render settings.
It is possible in keyshot.

Comment: Hello :). You can queue renders using the Render Burst addon. But sampling is set per scene, so it might be a bit more complicated.

Comment: I saw Render Burst which is for multiple camera only if I am not wrong? In Keyshot, you can change multiple setting for each render and then just add them in the render queue. This way I can sleep with renderings happening whole night :D